# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: BasicBSONList can only work with numeric keys, not:

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-security, spring-data

I'm trying to get all records from collection.Below is code for reference.

```
public class ParkingPlace{

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String placeId;

    @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private Date creationDate;

    @DBRef
    private List<Review> placeReviews;

    // Getters and setters
}

public class Review{

    @Id
    private String id;

    @DBRef
    private Author reviewAuthor;

    //getters and setters
}

public class Author{

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String fullName;

    //getters and setters
}

public class ParkingPlaceDAO{

    @Autowired
    MongoOperations mongoOperations;

    public List<ParkingPlace> getAllPlaces() {
        // new mongodb query
        Query query = new Query();
        // sort by date
        query.with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "creationDate"));
        // run query
        return mongoOperations.find(query, ParkingPlace.class);
    }
}
```

So in controller when I call `getAllPlaces()` method, it throws

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: BasicBSONList can only work with numeric keys, not: [reviewAuthor]
```

I've checked database and all collections and also fired query from mongo shell It gives me result.But not via code

Comment: can you show the ParkingPlace class?

Comment: @notionquuest updated

Comment: I have tried with latest Spring mongo version 1.10.4.RELEASE ... Am unable to reproduce the issue. Can you show your collection data for a parking place document (and its corresponding review and author documents).